# C++ Vector-based project to class-based version?

Tags: c++, class, vector

(Edit, I know it doesn't mean anything, but I need simple 'how can I use classes to categorize Students, and put 4 vectors into 1 vector like answer)I have an assignment in my university, and despite this is our last assignment of this semester, and I did the rest successfully, I got stuck and thought I need help at last. We did an assignment which we read student information files, and fill the information into 4 vectors which are name, lastname, idnumber and grade. We weren't allowed to use struct or classes before, but now our task is modify the exact same assignment but without using 4 vectors, we need to use just 1 vector, and 'Student' class. Our instructor shared the header file with us:

```
#ifndef student_h
#define student_h


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class Student{
public:
    Student();
    
    void setId(string);
    string getId() const;
    
    void setName(string);
    string getFirstName() const;
    string getLastName() const;
    
    void setPoints(double);
    double getPoints() const;
    
    
    void display(vector<Student>&, int);

    // Exam Functions

    void setExamWeights(double, double, double);
    double getGrade(string, double) const; 


private:
    string firstName;                     // name of the student (include middle name if exists)
    string lastName;                  // lastname of the student
    string ID;                       // identity number of the student
    double points;

    double midtermWeight; 
    double finalWeight;
    double hwWeight;
};



#endif
```

Even though I did the task perfectly before, my brain is tingling when I forced to use classes. I know it's such a bad behavior to share my code and ask for help from you, but I can't think anymore, and I need small hints or ideas about the algorithm. How can I modify my '4 vector' file reading project to '1 vector' one, with using class member functions? (I am not sharing the cpp file on purpose, because I don't want to cheat, just wanted to show you the header file that our instructor shared with us. If it's not clear, I can answer the clarification questions about our task.) Thank you so much.

Comment: is the answer simply `vector<Student>`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion, I couldn't explain what I need clearly. I have 4 vectors which are vector<String> Names, vector<string> lastnames, vector<string> student_id, vector<double> grades.   I somehow sort the students decending order, and print: cout << rank << student_id[rank] << name[rank] .... so on. (ie. 3. Alexander Johnson 78.7) Now I need to use maximum of 1 vector. How can I reach the name, lastname id and grades without using indexes of 4 vectors?

Comment: then yes, that's the answer. you will have a vector of students and you will access members of the elements. `vector<Student> students; cout<< rank << students[rank].get_name(); etc etc`

Comment: @Federico thank you so much I didn't know I could do this =) Helped me a lot !

Comment: _my brain is tingling when I forced to use classes_ Get used to it, it's going to happen a lot (using classes, I mean).

Comment: Sorry to say this. But if you take a breif look at the class notes or the reference book, things get easier. The instructor strangely seems to be doing fine.